# Data attribute overrides base class method: Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine

I have a class named *SearchQuery* and I named a data attribute as *query* (type: String); but the base class has a class method query(). So my *SearchQuery* class is as follow:

```
class SearchQuery(ndb.Model):
    query = ndb.StringProperty()
```

Now when I write:

```
SearchQuery.query()
```

I get:

```
TypeError: 'StringProperty' object is not callable
```

How do I call the *query* method? I will change my data member name but before changing I have to copy the data. For copying, *query()* has to be called.

Comment: You need to provide the data model class for use to work out what you have done.

Comment: I think its a bad practice to override a method (especially with a property) in the base class that isn't at least adding to the inherited method.  `query` is a classmethod of ndb.Model and and now you have to jump through hoops to use query as per answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call it at all; `SearchQuery.query()` is equal to `ndb.Query(kind="SearchQuery")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use *super*

If you have

```
class Parent(object):
 def query(self):
  print "Hello"
```

and

```
class Child(Parent):
 query = "Some string"
```

and you create a Child object defined like this

```
c = Child()
```

Then you can have access to the query function in *Parent* by using *super*:

```
super(Child, c).query()
```